# Backbonejs collection.fetch() enforce default model parameters

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections, backbone-model

After upgrading Backbonejs to 1.0, fetching collection from server enforces default properties that are not in response.

To be more specific I have created this test that can be verified in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pg2aU/422/).

Suppose we have a backbone model definition with default properties. Property `text` can be received from server in JSON `[{ "text": "updated", "id" : 1}]`, and property `selected` is maintained in client side.

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function () {
        return {
            text: 'default',
            selected: false
        };
    }    
});
```

If we use this setup and fetch data from server it will work correctly. Now suppose we add this model in backbone collection like this:

```
var Models = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: '/json/',
    model: Model
});
```

Create a new collection instance and populate with `fetch`:

```
var models = new Models();
models.fetch({
    update : true
});
```

After that, we take one model in the collection and change `selected` property to true:

```
var model = models.get(1);
model.set('selected', true);
```

Now if we call `fetch` the collection for the second time, backbone will clear our previously changed property to the default value `false` even if there was no such value in the response:

```
models.fetch({
    update : true
});
model = models.get(1);
```

Getting `selected` value will return `false` instead of our previously set `true`.

```
model.get('selected');
```

**Workaround:** comment out those properties, that are not received from server.

But in that case we loose lots of useful functionality from backbone.
Is this a regression in Backbonejs 1.0 or am I using this model in the wrong way?

Comment: I agree that it is expected from backbone to merge received properties to the specified defaults, but in this case, I am changing `selected` value to true _after_ we get that model from server. So the second time we fetch data from server, `selected` is already defined by initializer and changed by me. Using Backbone.js 0.9.10 with exactly the same code, is working differently in this jsfiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/FH4Nj/](http://jsfiddle.net/FH4Nj/), the way I would expect: defaults are applied only to the missing values, not just different.

Comment: A lot of people argue say that this isn't the way you're supposed to use Backbone. People like to keep the data on their models really pure.

Comment: But that is the way they show in Todo example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a regression in Backbone.js 1.0, that is fixed in current master.

[Closed issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2667)